# Free ip to connect z/os

Tags: ip, mainframe, zos

z/OS is a 64 bit OS run on IBM 390 mainframe hardware.  Connection can be made through 3270 emulators or more common SSH protocols from non-IBM operating systems like Windows or Linux.  Are there systems available on the Internet that can be accessed for free?

Comment: I do not understand your use of "ip". What does it stand for? Are you really asking about a free 3270 emulator? Plent around if you google. If you really mean a 'mainframe emulator' there is Hercules which is free. But it is the hardware emulator so you still need an os to run on it and the last free MVS is 3.4J(?) from the mid-1990s.

Comment: IP address of server, computer I mean, we are using to connect, Not asking for an emulator to connect. I dont have aTN3270 machine, I heard IBM provides some machines with global IP address, That can be connect using emulators.

Comment: Well, if they do then you would have to register with IBM for whichever service that you want to use. You will have to contact them.

Comment: Thank you. Thanks for your valuable openion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IBM sponsors a program called [Master the Mainframe](https://www.ibm.com/it-infrastructure/z/education/master-the-mainframe). If you are a student in high school or college/university, you are invited to participate in the Master the Mainframe contest. This contest includes hands-on exercises on an IBM Z system. Non-students can also access the learning materials year round, but are not eligible for prizes.

Answer (score 4):

IF you are interested in development of applications or services on z/OS there are a number of ways you can get access.  Since z/OS is a densely shared service it is hosted differently than cloud-like instance of Linux or other services.  Here is a starting point for access to free to low-cost services depending on the interested party's intention.

ZD&T is an s390 emulator that will run a z/OS instance on an x86 Linux based system.  This option has various pricing options which vary from free to some $'s depending on the intent of the consumer.  This allows you to host your own z/OS instance for experimentation and development.  These can be run in the cloud, on your laptop or hosted in a private cloud.

[Z Development and Test Environment (ZD&T)](https://developer.ibm.com/mainframe/products/z-systems-development-test-environment/)

zTrial is another option if you have a specific use case that you want to explore.  The trials are typically focused on experimenting with specific program products and use cases.  They help to get hands on experience with a product quickly by providing images that have all software installed and have a set of guided scripts that help the user explore the system.

[IBM zTrial Program](https://www.ibm.com/it-infrastructure/z/resources/trial)

IBM also provides ISVs access to free instances for integration and other testing but you would need to contact IBM as part of their business partner program.  This is probably the most complicated method of access as it can be free but does require an agreement with IBM.

[IBM Partner World](https://www-356.ibm.com/partnerworld/wps/servlet/ContentHandler/partnerworld-program-overview)

Answer (score 2):

IBM has a zTrial program that lets you provision a sandbox z/OS environment that you can do whatever you want with. I believe the images last for 3 days and after that time you can provision a new image for another 3 days. Here's a link to zTrial:

https://www.ibm.com/it-infrastructure/z/resources/trial